# Nodejs - capture OPEN event on server side

Tags: node.js, events

Client is sending some data using once. But I want to capture the `OPEN` event on the server side...

Client side code:

```
const ws = new WebSokcet('ws://localhost:7887');

ws.once('open', () => {
    ws.send('TEST|1234\0')
})
```

On the server side I tried the following but it never fires.

```
websocket.on('open', data => {

    console.log("test");

});
```

Based on the comment in https://github.com/espruino/Espruino/issues/1227#issuecomment-325630041 it seems the `open` is client only.

How can I capture the data sent only once?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are confusing events. "open", "websocket", "close" they all relate to the lifecycle of the connection. You will not receive information there.

On the other hand, "message" is to receive information.

You are missing a message event on the server:

```
websocket.on('message', function (msg) {
   console.log('test')
})
```

EDIT: Replying to the extended question in the comments. Basically what you want is to build a protocol on top of the websocket library to enable authentication or others. If you want to implement it yourself, then you should add different type of messages. Say:

```
websocket.on('mmessage', function (msg) {
  try {
    // JSON parse must always be try catch, since string might not be a json and async errors are really bad
    const data = JSON.parse(msg.toString())
    if (!('type' in data')) {
       // We require type in property, probably go on the error route
       throw new Error(...)
    }
    const type = data.type
    if (type === AUTH) {
       /// ....
    } else if (type == MSG) {
       const token = data.token
       // check token, which is required in every message
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO log and probably return feedback to the client
  }
})
```

On the client you would do something similar:

```
ws.once('open', () => {
   ws.send(JSON.stringify({type: AUTH, data: {pass: '1234', user: 'TEST'}}))
})
```

If you use wrapper on top of websocket then you have easier code. I think that with socket.io for example you can send an object and it will be stringified by you

Comment: I have a message event. But message event gets other data too. Where as the first open event is sending some code which needs to be stored in a variable on the server side.

Comment: I mean during the login stage, a code is sent which I want to store in a variable on the server side. The message event then continues with other data which I don't want to store

Comment: is there a websocket event that only runs once on the server side during the first handshake?

Comment: @User no there isn't. When the client receives 'open' the handshake is already done, that's why you can do ws.send.

What you can do is send different kind of messages, but you'll need server logic to filter one or the other

Comment: I'm using the message event to forward data to netsocket. But the data client sends during the first handshake is something I need to store on the server side.

Comment: okay any examples or links to related the server side filtering I can implement?

Comment: @User I've edited the example with a very basic protocol that you could implement, it is very rudimentary but it could be enough for your purposes. There are other ways to implement authentication, for example if you are using a reverse proxy like Nginx, it could handle the authentication before the http(s) connection is upgraded to websocket, but I don't have a link for that and it requires more infrastructure